# How to fill a form inside a modal using JQuery and Laravel?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, laravel-4

I'm trying to retrieve an user's data from my database and put it in a form inside a modal in order to edit it. I've tried using the JQuery .post method to get a Json, but it fails and sends me a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm using an example on the internet as reference but I can't get it to work, I think the request is not getting any data to send, as some tests I made showed. I'm using the Laravel 4 framework, here's the JQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.edit').click(function()
    {
        $('[name=user]').val($(this).attr('id'));
        var faction="<?php echo URL::to('getuser/data'); ?>";
        var fdata = $('#val').serialize();
        $.post(faction,fdata,function(json)
        {
            if(json.success)
            {
                $('#formEdit input[name="name_edit"]').val(json.name);
                $('#formEdit input[name="lastname_edit"]').val(json.lastname);
                $('#formEdit input[name="mlastname_edit"]').val(json.mlastname);
                $('#formEdit input[name="email_edit"]').val(json.email);
                $('#formEdit input[name="username_edit"]').val(json.username);
                if(json.level==true)
                {
                    $('#level.prop').prop('checked','true');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#level').removeAttr('checked');
                }

            }
        }).fail(function(msg) {
          alert(msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the button that calls the modal and sends the post request:

```
<span class="btn btn-info">{{HTML::link('#Edit','Editar',array('class'=>'edit','id'=>$user->id,'data-toggle'=>'modal','title'=>$user->name))}}</span>
```

And this is the controller:

```
<?php 

class getuserController extends BaseController
{
    public function postData()
    {
    $user_id=Input::get('user');
    $user=User::find($user_id);
    $data=array(
        'success'=>true,
        'id'=>$user->id,
        'name'=>$user->name,
        'lastname'=>$user->lastname,
        'mlastname'=>$user->mlastname,
        'email'=>$user->email,
        'username'=>$user->username,
        'level'=>$user->$user->level
    );
    return Response::json($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some changes on my code, however, my laravel.log file keeps sending me an ErrorException with the message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in my controller file.

Comment: I put an alert with the value of the data I'm sending, it returns 'user=35', being 35 the ID number of the user I want to edit, I want to know if my controller can use this data or if this is an error that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code to work, I was missing a hidden text field with `name = 'user'` and `id = val` where the user's ID was stored, that was why it didn't send any `value`; also I had a syntax error in my controller, in `$user->level`, I wrote it twice, simple as that, kind of embarrassing but I'm glad I could work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax in combination with Laravel requires sending the _token. This can easily be done by having the token as a meta tag `<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` on every page.

Then when setting form data send the token with it using `var token = $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr('content');`

I do mine like below:

```
    $(document).on('click', ".config", function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/ajax/load',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id, _token: token },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $(obj).each(function(key, value) {
                    var options = '<option value="' +value.id+ '">' +value.name+ '</option>';
                    $("#new_sub_element").append(options);
                });
            }
        });
```

The setting of the values can be parsed to your modal window... Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: The error 500 is caused by not sending the _token. By setting the token in a meta tag, then getting it before sending the ajax post this can be fixed. Otherwise you need to add it as a hidden field

Comment: I changed the ajax method to include the token field, however, I keep getting the exception I mentioned in a comment above.